# Save QR code text in memory and show it in another activity

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I have an app that scans QR code. And it to show in another activity. How to pass QR Code text to another activity? Or save it in memory?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
    private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        zXingScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(zXingScannerView);
        zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        zXingScannerView.startCamera();
    }    
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
    }
    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Result");
        builder.setMessage(result.getText());
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();         
        zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass data to your `Activity` through the `Intent` using `Extras`, [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application).

Answer (score 1):

Call  method `startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, YourCallbackActivity.class), 1001);`
Use `setResult()` method for get call back in another activity.

```
@Override
public void handleResult (Result result) {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result",String.valueOf(rawResult));
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

now

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
            //do whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

I already did, hope it will help you!!